# jQuery Ajax and HTML callback

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, callback

I have this code, that executes when a link is clicked:

```
$.get(file.html, function(data) {           
  $('selector_1').html($(data).find('selector_2').html());
});
```

I would like to modify the code in such a way that when I click a link, the `$.get` command runs while `selector_1` fades out, and when the HTML of `selector_1` is placed, it fades back in.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `selector_1` and `selector_2` are just a sample, try the below code which uses the `fadeOut` callback.

```
$('selector_1').fadeOut(300, function() {        
    $.get(file.html, function(data) {
        $('selector_1')
            .html($(data).find('selector_2').html())
            .fadeIn();
    });    
});
```

Also note that the `$.get` is wrapped inside the `fadeOut` callback, so that the transition is perfect.

> This is also the solution I thought of, but the problem is that the `$.get` command is sent after the fade out and not simultaneously - I want the `$.get` command to execute immediately.

See below.

```
$('selector_1').fadeOut(300);
$.get(file.html, function(data) {
    $('selector_1')
      .html($(data).find('selector_2').html())
      .fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: > This is also the solution I thought of, but the problem is that the $.get command is sent after the fade out and not simultaneously - I want the $.get command to execute immediately.

Comment: @afcdesign Then just move it outside `fadeOut`

Comment: if I do that, the html placement can be seen while the fadeout happens. That is what I want to avoid.

Comment: The time taken by `$.get` is not constant. If it is too fast, then you will see the html placement.. to avoid that you should move that inside callback.. but as you know.. it would simply be triggered only after fadeOut.

Comment: can't I just get the $.get object as a variable that I can use? Then it is triggered and stored in cache, for me to use when I want.